# Spreading jQuery buttons vertically in a longer P or DIV

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, button

I have prepared [a simple jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/afarber/56tshoL6/) for my question.

There is an array of jQuery buttons in a center-aligned P-element:

[image: buttons]

```
<P ALIGN="center">
        <BUTTON ID="recallBtn">Recall</BUTTON>
        <BUTTON ID="shuffleBtn">Shiffle</BUTTON>
        <BUTTON ID="swapBtn">Swap</BUTTON>
        <BUTTON ID="skipBtn">Skip</BUTTON>
        <BUTTON ID="resignBtn">Resign</BUTTON>
        <BUTTON ID="pileBtn" DISABLED>Pile</BUTTON>
        <BUTTON ID="playBtn">Play</BUTTON>
</P>
```

As you can see the buttons are displayed in 2 rows because the paragraph is too long - and the buttons touch each other vertically.

How could I add some vertical padding between the buttons please?

I have tried adding `<P ALIGN="center" STYLE="line-height: 200%">` and similar things (line-height 2 or 2em, also tried using `DIV`) - but there was no visual change at all.

To give my question some context - my HTML5 game is embedded both in a [Facebook canvas](https://apps.facebook.com/slova-farbera/) and in a Wordpress website, and [my custom CSS](https://slova.de/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-child/style.css) is minimal.

Comment: try  button { margin-top: 5px; }

Comment: try adding margin to all button `<BUTTON ID="recallBtn" STYLE="margin-bottom: 10px;">Recall</BUTTON>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add margin to `.ui-button` class

working example
https://jsfiddle.net/p79dpvww/